# what is the difference between $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] 'store' and 'website'

Tags: magento-1.7, configuration, multistore

For the creation of multistore magento we use following code

```
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

What will be the difference if we use `website` instead of `store` in `$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';` code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I want to correct KESHAV_PHP here.

`$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']` defines the type of entity which is used to select the store in the end. If you define a specific store by passing here `store`, then the store is loaded. This means espacially (in contradiction to what keshav wrote), that it doesn't matter wether the store is part of the default website or not.

If you pass `website`, then the store is loaded which is default for the website.

`$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']` defines the code of the website or store, as defined in the tables `core_website.code` and `core_store.code`.

The whole process can be found here:

```
\Mage_Core_Model_App::_initCurrentStore
switch ($scopeType) {
        case 'store':
            $this->_currentStore = $scopeCode;
            break;
        case 'group':
            $this->_currentStore = $this->_getStoreByGroup($scopeCode);
            break;
        case 'website':
            $this->_currentStore = $this->_getStoreByWebsite($scopeCode);
            break;
        default:
            $this->throwStoreException();
    }
```

Where `getStoreByWebsite` only gets the default group and then calls `getStoreByGroup` which gets the default store for the group.

Comment: Fabulous explanation.+1 for digging core :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently am also working on different website in magento site.In my project am creating three websites with stores that specific to website.

**$server[mage_run_type]:website** mean that when the site is load , magento load the website .

$server[mage_runtype]:store means that magento load the store of default website.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/multiple-website-setup